# How to get old value from JSF/ADF validator?

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf

I have a requirement to validate an JSF/ADF input field **only** if the value of that field changed by users. If the value on the page is the same as the value in the model, skip validation for that field.

I am using JSF and Oracle ADF Faces, I know JSF life cycle and I can make my own converter or validator, but I can't find the old value anywhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

During validation the old value should be available by `UIInput#getValue()`.

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    Object oldValue = ((UIInput) component).getValue();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I need to cast the UIcomponent to CoreInputText instead of UIIput, but other than that, it works.

Comment: ddi you really have to mention that? :) anyways thanks @BalusC it works for me!